# Convert big size array into hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array of size 35K and want to convert it into hash. I was able to convert an array of size 12K with the following method.

```
a = []
12000.times { |i| a << i }
Hash[*a]
```

But, When I try arrays having size more than 12K, it raises SystemStackError: stack level too deep error.

Can anyone suggest? What is going wrong?

Comment: nothing wrong with your script, works on my machine(ruby1.9.3-p125 OSX)  tho it is not an efficient way to do what you do, I think your stack runs out of space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
a = [*1..1_000_000].to_a
b = {}
a.each_slice(2){|k,v| b[k] = v}
```